# Azure SQL Foreign Key with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015

I have an Azure SQL database created in the management station, I connect to it on Visual Studio 2015, I create tables Player and Team, I'm trying to create a foreign key to reference team name but I keep getting the following error;

SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[Team]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

From looking at online sources, mainly MSDN, I have tried a few ways to solve this issue but have had no luck. Here is my SQL code;

Team Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Team] (
    [Id]             INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]           VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    [Wins]           INT          NOT NULL,
    [Draws]          INT          NOT NULL,
    [Losses]         INT          NOT NULL,
    [GoalsFor]       INT          NOT NULL,
    [GoalsAgainst]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [GoalDifference] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Points]         INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Player Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Player] (
    [Id]      INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]    VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    [Team]    VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    [Goals]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [Assists] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Apps]    INT          NOT NULL,
    [Club] VARCHAR (30)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Player_Club] FOREIGN KEY ([Club]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Team]([Name]),
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Store TeamID instead of team name in players table. (And you don't need an extra key in team table...)

Comment: With this change, I get an error due to the datatypes not being the same, as in Club is varchar and Id is an int

Comment: You have to adjust datatype too, and store the id, not the name...

Comment: Would you mind being more specific, I'm just making sure I'm getting it right

Comment: Wait a minute, what's the difference between club and team?

Comment: I was making a mistake doing that, it was to see if naming was the issue, Club represents team that the player is on

Comment: Your answer before fixed the error

Comment: The one below? (Now back.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Team] (
    [Id]             INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]           VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    [Wins]           INT          NOT NULL,
    [Draws]          INT          NOT NULL,
    [Losses]         INT          NOT NULL,
    [GoalsFor]       INT          NOT NULL,
    [GoalsAgainst]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [GoalDifference] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Points]         INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Player Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Player] (
    [Id]      INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]    VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    [Team]    VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    [Goals]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [Assists] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Apps]    INT          NOT NULL,
    [TeamId]  INT          NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Player_Club] FOREIGN KEY ([TeamId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Team]([Id]),
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```